# Bash: check if hostname is v-q* how to use wildcards?

Tags: bash, scripting, programming-languages

I have the next code and I need it to echo 1 if the hostname matches with v-qai01 or any other v-q* servers:

```
if [ `hostname -s` -eq `v-q*` ]; then
        echo "1"
fi
```

Im having several errors:

```
./run.sh: line 3: v-q*: command not found
./run.sh: line 3: [: v-qai01: unary operator expected
```

Any suggestions please?

What if I have the next case?

```
hostname=`hostname -s`

portalesWildcard=v-*ws*
qaiservers={'v-qai01' 'v-qai02'}
portales={'t1wsyellar01' }


if [[ ${hostname} = ${qaiservers} ]]; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use double square brackets and the `=` operator will accept wildcards:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(hostname -s) = v-q* ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

It also has a `=~` operator for regex matches when you need more advanced string matching. This would check that the host name also ends with one or more digits:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(hostname -s) =~ ^v-q.*[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: What if I have an array of hostnames and I want to check if it belongs to the current server hostname?

Comment: @BoDiE2003, that deserves a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the `case` statement:

```
case $(hostname -s) in
  v-q*) echo yes ;;
  *) echo no ;;
esac
```

Comment: [Guides says](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) there must be `esac` on the end of the case statement, not `done`.

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem that the original poster had was that they used backticks around the string:

```
if [ `hostname -s` -eq `v-q*` ]; then
```

rather than string quotes. Backticks tell the shell to execute the string within them as a command. In this case, the shell tried to execute:

```
v-q*
```

which failed.

Comment: More commonly known as 'backticks'

Comment: Edited for terminology and clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove `v-q` from the beginning of the string. If the condition is true, your hostname matches `v-q*`

```
hostname=`hostname -s`
if ! [ "${hostname#v-q}" = "${hostname}" ]; then
  echo "1"
fi
```

Comment: what if I have an array on the hostanmes list?